# Why cant I setRetainInstance(true) for nested fragment?

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

As I understand, It means that I must use `Bundle instance` to store fragment's data. But what is a purpose of this limitation?

```
public void setRetainInstance(boolean retain) {
    if (retain && mParentFragment != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Can't retain fragements that are nested in other fragments");
    }
    mRetainInstance = retain;
}
```

Comment: `setRetainInstance()` relies upon `onCreateNonConfigurationInstance()` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` on `Activity`. That is easy enough for fragments managed directly by the activity. However, for arbitrarily-deeply nested fragments, probably they decided that it would get too complicated, particularly if the parent of a retained nested fragment is not itself retained.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, now I understand. So, there is no other way to keep nested fragment's fields without saving it to `Bundle`? Even if parent fragment is `setRetainInstance(true)`?

Comment: Well, personally, I avoid nested fragments entirely. The code that you list shows that you cannot retain nested fragments, regardless of whether the parent fragment itself is retained.

Comment: @CommonsWare How do you handle situations when you need `retain fragment` inside `ViewPager`? Is there any implementation that can put pages(fragments) directly in `Activity`?

Comment: I do not use a `ViewPager` inside of a fragment, so I do not need nested fragments. Actually, more recently, I have moved to using [`RecyclerViewPager`](https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager), which implements a `ViewPager`-style horizontal page-at-a-time swipe pattern using `RecyclerView`. As a result, even my pages are not fragments.